# Rows not populating with multiple primary keys and constraints (Oracle DB)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I created a table `RAW_Table`, which has two primary keys `SEARCHID` and `SERVICE_INVOKED`.

When the program runs, my database updates `SEARCHID`. This is unique and for every `SEARCHID` generated, there can be multiple `SERVICE_INVOKED`.

The table should have an individual row for every `SERVICE_INVOKED`. At the moment, only one row is ever populated, even if there are multiple services invoked. What should I do? Here is the SQL query for creating the RAW_TABLE.....

```
CREATE TABLE "SAT_RAW_TABLE" 
   (    
    "SEARCHID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) , 
    "USER_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "SAT_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "STATE" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "ZIPCODE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "TERM" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "BANDWIDTH" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "SERVICE_INVOKED" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) , 
    "SERVICE_REQUEST" CLOB, 
    "SERVICE_RESPONSE" CLOB, 
    "INVOKED_DATETIME" date,
    PRIMARY KEY (SEARCHID,SERVICE_INVOKED)
    );
```

Comment: You can't have two primary keys - what you have is a _compound_ primary key.  And you should VERY RARELY update a primary key.  Can you show sample data before and after what you're trying to do? (You can leave out the other columns if they're not relevant to your problem)

Comment: That is correct, to fix this, we ran this script. ALTER TABLE SAT_RAW_TABLE 
DROP CONSTRAINT SYS_C001274759;

ALTER TABLE SAT_RAW_TABLE
ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_C001274759 PRIMARY KEY 
(
  SEARCHID 
, SERVICE_INVOKED 
)
ENABLE;

Comment: to me it sounds as creation 3 tables is required: "sat_search", "sat_service" and "sat_raw_table"... sat_raw_table could contains only 2 fields: [search_id; service_invoked]... this let you easy make updates without recreating PK

Comment: The end table should look something like this,                            SearchID Username SAT-NAME   SERVICE INVOKED
100       ABCD     SAT1      Service1
100       ABCD     SAT1      Service2
100       ABCD     SAT1      Service3
200       PQRS     SAT2      SERVICE1
200       PQRS     SAT2      SERVICE2

Comment: @DStanley: The expected table should look like what I mentioned above. What can be done to get tables this way?